# Erasing portion of a stoke in UWP

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas, eraser

I am using the new Ink technology for Windows 10, by using InkCanvas/InkPresenter in UWP. Ink rendering is really nice, except I can't seem to be able to erase only a portion of a stroke. I am looking at OneNote, that I am assuming is using the same technology, and they do offer erasing of portion of a stroke. I know this wasn't possible when the InkCanvas/InkPresenter was first introduced, but I was wondering if there is a method to achieve this? Some way to mask the stroke to fake the eraser, maybe? Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a look at Microsoft's Coloring book sample where you can erase cell(Portion of stroke). They have created a Custom InkToolbar with flood fill, erase cell and much more.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook

Hope it helps.

### Edit

You can intercept default inkcanvas events and set handler to avoid the event to take place.

```
CoreInkIndependentInputSource core = CoreInkIndependentInputSource.Create(inkCanvas.InkPresenter); core.PointerPressing += ViewModel.Core_PointerPressing; 
core.PointerReleasing += ViewModel.Core_PointerReleasing; 
core.PointerMoving += ViewModel.Core_PointerMoving;
```

Comment: Really nice example. Unfortunately erase cell is NOT erasing a portion of the stroke, but just a filled area. I am trying to develop my own algorithm, but I will need to disable the pen eraser. Do you have a suggestion for that, or should I post another question about it?

Comment: You can intercept default inkcanvas events and set handler to avoid the event to take place.

CoreInkIndependentInputSource  core = CoreInkIndependentInputSource.Create(inkCanvas.InkPresenter);

core.PointerPressing += ViewModel.Core_PointerPressing;
core.PointerReleasing += ViewModel.Core_PointerReleasing;
core.PointerMoving += ViewModel.Core_PointerMoving;